# Change mysql root user password using shell script

Tags: mysql, shell, automation, sh

I am trying to change user password using a shell script as below

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql.server start
mysql -u root << EOF
  SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD(‘admin’);
EOF
```

But I am getting below error:-

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '‘admin’)' at line 1

Instead of SET PASSSWORD command if use something else will work like if I use 'create database databasename' will works.

.

> Update1:

If I use "admin" or 'admin' instead of ‘admin’, I got below error.

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '“admin2”)' at line 1

.

> Update2:

When using -e flag I got below error

> ./mysql.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
>   ./mysql.sh: line 3:`mysql -u root -padmin -e “SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD(‘admin2’);”'

Comment: `‘admin’` can you wrap in these quotes? Try `"admin"` or `'admin'` instead

Comment: Thanks for replying, I think issue was due to editor :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use mysql -e instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql.server start
mysql -u root -e "SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD('admin');"
```

Comment: I think issue was due to some editor, I wrote same script using another editor and vola your and mine script both will work. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying above and not getting it to work. I ran the below in my terminal and it worked! *(Remember to set the password you want ;) )*

```
mysql -u root -e "SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost = PASSWORD('mypassword')";
```